# In theory, would a particle with sufficient energy to form its own black hole, be so spread out as to avoid it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, mass-energy, event-horizon

There have been quite a few questions on the lines of "is there a maximum energy for a photon?" I'm curious about the implications of a "sufficiently highly energetic particle" existing.

If a particle was a point object, or a limited small size, we could eventually supply enough energy to it (in theory and as far as we know) to meet the conditions for an event horizon to form. On the other hand, this gives the particle enormous momentum, and therefore we'd actually expect quantum effects to spread its probable locations much more widely over space (uncertainty principle), possibly frustrating our attempt to cram enough mass-energy into a small enough volume.

Ignoring the rapid evaporation time of microscopic black holes,  what theoretically happens?

Can an event horizon be created this way, or does uncertainty (or other quantum effects) set a theoretical limit to the achievable energy density that can be reached with any single particle?

Comment: Can you explain how  energy, as opposed to mass, can cause a black hole to form?  For example, in vacuum space you can superpose photons without (significant) interaction.

Comment: If that's totally incorrect, then the question is meaningless.  But two reasons for doubting that - mass energy equivalence, and the cosmological speculation on primordial BH which would i gather form before anything other than perhaps energy and a few types of particle (but no dense mass bodies) existed.

Comment: Kinetic energy doesn’t bend spacetime. So your question is moot.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)

Comment: @safesphere that could be an answer.  But I can't tell whether Kugelblitz theory requires multiple photons "running into each other" or whether a single photon of sufficiently short wavelength would suffice.  For that matter, how would such a photon be theoretically created?

Comment: @safesphere - never heard of the term but that link is a perfect answer, thank you!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If a photon is coming to you, you can make its wavelength much shorter by moving toward this photon yourself at near the speed of light. Of course the fact that you are moving fast would not make a photon a black hole, so a single photon (or anything with kinetic energy) does not bend spacetime. Whether more than one photon can make a black hole is a good question.